# Getting the NServiceBus WCF Integration Sample To Work

Tags: wcf, nservicebus

I'm new to WCF.  If I run the sample it just gives the below error

> Exception when starting endpoint,
>   error has been logged. Reason: HTTP
>   could not register URL
>   http://+:9009/services/cancelOrder/.
>   Your process does not have access
>   rights to this namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353
>   for detail

s).

Do I need to do something to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, load VS2010 by right clicking and "run as administrator".

Comment: I ended up just creating a shortcut that runs as admin by default.